# Streaming file (created on a mobile phone) to S3 via node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mobile, amazon-s3, thumbnails

I have a mobile phone application where I allow users to take photographs and persist the picture file to S3. I am using a Node.js server to do the persistence to S3.

On the node.js server side I have exposed an API which does the following:

1. Constructs an in memory buffer of file data sent by the client (mobile device which took the photograph).
2. Persists this data in local file system.
3. Creates a thumbnail from original picture file in local fs (Thumbnail creation is another requirement I have). Persists thumbnail to local fs. I use easyimg for thumbnail creation.
4. Persists original pic and thumbnail from local fs to S3

I have few questions in the process above:

- The above process works for me, however I want to avoid steps 1. and 2. (the in memory buffer creation and persistence to local file system) as node is just acting as a conduit for the data to be streamed to S3. Can someone give me pointers to code to do the same?
- Is easyimg a good way to create thumbnail? What are the advantages and disadvantages of using this module? Is there something better in terms of performance and ease of use?
- I am ok with some delay in thumbnail generation. So the thumbnail file need not be persisted along with the original file in S3. Does this help in any way?

Comment: if the image is not on disk or in RAM, how can it be sent away or resized?

Comment: I am mainly interested in doing streaming to S3 via node for which the entire file need not be in memory. As I mentioned thumbnail generation need not happen at the same time as persistence to S3. So one thought I have is I may have a background task that sweeps S3 buckets periodically and generates thumbnails for files that dont have one.

Comment: my concern was that without the whole file available locally, either in ram or on disk, a thumbnail would be impossible. if you can do it later, i see no problem. you should be able to pipe() the incoming data to S3 without caching. look into the stream interfaces, readable and writable.